# How does bagging affect linear model assumptions?

Tags: linear-model, bagging

Linear regression has assumptions. How does bagging affect model assumptions for linear regression?

Also, should you build a bagged linear model with correlated and statistically significant variables only? Does it matter if uncorrelated or statistically insignificant variables are used to build a bagged linear model?

Comment: How is bagging supposed to work for linear regression? Something like averaging multiple models as here: [Can I merge multiple linear regressions into one regression?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/546844/can-i-merge-multiple-linear-regressions-into-one-regression). But that won't reduce the variance. Or is this for some sort of regularisation and non-linear estimators?

Answer (score 2):

> linear regression has model assumptions. how does bagging effect model assumptions for linear regression?

The bagging procedures do not affect the model assumptions of linear regression.  Bagging is a technique to reduce the variance of the model you use to bag (which in the case of linear regression is not super useful since it is a high bias low variance method to begin with).

> also should you build a bagged linear model with correlated and statistically significant variables only?

No. Variable selection via p values is fraught with problems, as I and others have written about previously elsewhere on this site.